# How should I show my step-mother?

Tags: ancestry.com

I am using an online service for my family tree, and this got me wondering. How should I show my step-mother and my half-siblings? I mean, will my father's marriage to my step-mother be on the same level, underneath or something else?

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://boards.ancestry.com/topics.software.ancfamtree/651.1/mb.ashx) gave me the answer. When I opted to add child, the system gave me two options; **my step-mother and my father** and **my step-mother and unknown person**. This allowed me to achieve my goal.